# How to change color based on random number

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to make a part that will change color depending on the seed.

Example:

```lua
if seed = 1 then
    part.Color3 = red
end
```

which is like this, but with randomization

Nothing, im really dont know to make or try this

Comment: Do you want `math.random`? http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the items, then use the math.random function to pick one out of the list.

```lua
-- create a list of colors
local colors = {
    Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0), --red
    Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0), --green
    Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 255), --blue
}

-- select a random number based on the length of the list
local index = math.random(#colors)

-- choose a color from the list
local rndColor = colors[index]

-- locate the part
local part = script.Parent

-- assign the color to the part
part.Color3 = rndColor
```